# Robot Framework - Store the scren shot in a folder with the name as current timestamp

Tags: robotframework

I want to store the screen shots as well as the logs and report generated by execution into a folder witha a name as current timestamp

Like a folder name as "Test"247105151023 
 if the date is 24-Jul-2015 and time is 3:10:23PM

Comment: What do you gonna use for making screenshots?

Comment: It all depends on which tool makes the screenshots? self library? AutoIT? Selenium? some external library?

Answer (score 0):

You can specify output folder with pybot -d Test247105151023. It will create folder if it is missing.

There are several ways to start pybot with timestamp as parameter. One is using Python datetime to calculate your timestamp and subprocess to start pybot with parameters.